# Overwrite custom node view fail

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I've created a function that have custom content type and all went well, but the problem is now I'm unable to overwrite the node view page:

Here are my functions:

```
function xxx_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'xxx_print' => array(
      //'variables' => array('node' => NULL),
      'function' => 'theme_xxx_print',
    ),
  );
}

function theme_xxx_print($node) {
  return '<div>test</div>';
}
```

Comment: Did you cleared the cache

Comment: yes, I did nothing happened, the current node view is presented by panel

Answer (score 0):

If you are using panels node view template for your node view then your template file and node theme declarations would be overruled by panels.

If you want to verify, disable the panel node view. Make sure to flush your caches then visit a node you have and your theme override/addition will be there.

Comment: upon checking, my node was not using panels, I still can not overwrite the theme using my current functions

Comment: Can you provide more details on the content type, related template files, related template.php functions and related panels config(if there is). Have you tried also just creating a plain drupal site and tested your code? I believe your code works so it may be something overriding it in your project.